# Replacing numbers within a range with a factor

Tags: r, data-processing, r-factor

Given a dataframe column which is a series of integers (age), I want to convert ranges of integers into ordinal variables.

My current code doesn't work, how do I do this?

```
df <- read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/822467/df.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

df[(df >= 0)  & (df <= 14)] <- "Age1"
df[(df >= 15) & (df <= 44)] <- "Age2"
df[(df >= 45) & (df <= 64)] <- "Age3"
df[(df > 64)] <- "Age4"

table(df)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `cut` to do this in one step:

```
dfc <- cut(df$x, breaks=c(0, 15, 45, 56, Inf))
str(dfc)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "(0,15]","(15,45]",..: 3 4 3 2 2 4 2 2 4 4 ...
```

Once you are satisfied that the `breaks` are correctly specified, you can then also use the `labels` argument to relabel the levels:

```
dfc <- cut(df$x, breaks=c(0, 15, 45, 56, Inf), labels=paste("Age", 1:4, sep=""))
str(dfc)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "Age1","Age2",..: 3 4 3 2 2 4 2 2 4 4 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you know what was wrong with what I was originally trying to do?

Comment: @RJ -- Try this (and then compare it line 5 of your code) to see what went wrong: `c(65, 99, 100, 104, "Age3", "Age2") > 64`.

Comment: To obtain an ordered factor (which was mentioned in the OP), include `ordered_result = TRUE` in `cut()`.

Comment: @Josh O'Brien I see, I understand now. the integers and alphanumeric lie on a continuum. 1 - 10, A - Z

Comment: @RJ- Yep, that's it. And since even the integers are converted to character strings, they are sorted in a dictionary order (rather than by magnitude). e.g. `sort(c(1:12, 100, letters[1:5]))`