# New column based on multiple conditions - do not replace ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to create a new column in my data.frame: `mad$season` that is filled with conditional categories:

```
mad$season <- ifelse(mad$dayofyear <81, "winter", "")
mad$season <- ifelse((mad$dayofyear>=80) & (mad$dayofyear<=108), "spring", "")
mad$season <- ifelse(mad$dayofyear >108, "summer", "")
```

Similar to this example: [R: Add multiple new columns based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576063/r-add-multiple-new-columns-based-on-multiple-conditions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, each line of code replaces the first - and NULL doesn't appear to work.

Any suggestions?

This question is different from [Replacing numbers within a range with a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222525/replacing-numbers-within-a-range-with-a-factor?noredirect=1&lq=1) because I wanted to add a new column, not replace the number with a factor.

Comment: You can use `cut` for this `mad$season <- with(mad, cut(dayofyear, breaks = c(-Inf, 80, 108, Inf), labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer")))`

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cut` to do this without multiple `ifelse` statements.  Just specify the `breaks` and the `labels` to create the 'season' column

```
mad$season <- with(mad, cut(dayofyear, breaks = c(-Inf, 80, 108, Inf),
         labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of you knowing what was wrong, in order to use multiple `ifelse` statements to do as you'd like, you have to nest them.

```
mad$season <- ifelse(mad$dayofyear <81, "winter", 
                     ifelse((mad$dayofyear>=80) & (mad$dayofyear<=108), "spring", 
                            ifelse(mad$dayofyear >108, "summer", "")))
```

This way, each time the ifelse if finds FALSE, it moves to the next available ifelse. Otherwise you are indeed rewriting the object.

As akrun has commented, `cut` is the much more clever way to do this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was wondering if I could nest it - that makes more sense. Thanks!